# Internet connection sharing from PC to Phone over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have already read other questions relating to sharing Internet connection from the Phone to the PC. This as most of us know works out of the box in latest Ubuntu (and for some it just needs to either add an additional package or install a package in the cell). This is not the case here.

What I am looking for is the following:

1. Internet arrives at the PC via ethernet cable.
2. PC has Bluetooth and I would like to share the internet via Bluetooth.
3. Phone should connect to Bluetooth and receive Internet via Bluetooth.

How can I share an Internet connection via Bluetooth from the PC to the Phone. Already tested Blueman and is not working for this.

I am using a Nokia n900 and a Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: The answer depends on what kind of phone you want to use.Not every modern phone can see PAND/DUND as network.As far as I know only Palm(old), Nokia N9/N00, Symbians60v2/3 based phones(requires gnubox) & iphone has the capability to do that. Android with ICS may work(Only DUN).You can install PAND/DUND from 'bluez-compact' package. Get help from these topics: [post1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=471441), [post2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PalmBluetoothHowto), [post3](http://blog.chewearn.com/2010/09/30/ubuntu-lucid-lynx-mobile-broadband-tethering-to-nokia-n95-part-2/).

Comment: In my case I am using a N900 and a Huawei MT8220. Also none of the links you posted will solve this problem. They only apply for very old versions. In some cases VERY old versions.

Comment: @RohithRaveendran you should actually move the answer here since that would be a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Musher are you using a phone that tethering over bluetooth can be enabled on?

Comment: @Musher why not use WiFi?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Fairly certain - LG G4 on T-Mobile

Comment: @daltonfury42 because by default android doesn't support ad-hoc connections, and for some reason setting it to 'infrastructure' doesn't work either

Comment: @Musher, I could get it working on couple of laptops by setting it to `ap` by editing the configs. 1) Create a hotspot 2) Switch off WiFi. 3) Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<hotspot-name>`, set the value from `infrastructure` or `adhoc` to `ap`. 4) Save and exit, switch on wifi. 5) Start the previously created Hotspot (From `Connect to hidden Networks...`)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any good way using native bluetooth app that ships with ubuntu but I am going to use a pretty old app called blueman.

install it using

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Now from unity search (from dash) for blueman and you will get bluetooth manager click on that and you will get window and blueman service will be enabled.

now you can see two bluetooth icons on top panel of unity. one will be native and other will be blueman's

click on blueman's icon and click local services.

[image: selecting local services]

---

Now a `new window **Local Services** pops up`, in it click on 'network' and enable Network Access point, click apply and save it.

[image: enabling network]

Now you can access internet using bluetooth of your computer after pairing them and connecting.

Comment: The small downside seems to be that then there are two identical Bluetooth icons in the top panel, as seen on the screenshot above. A bit confusing, but works.

Comment: In 12.04 it was working file. But now in 14.04 it's not working. I can't see the `blueman` icon either.

Comment: You can start the **Local Services...** by executing `blueman-services`.

Comment: I started **Local Services** with `blueman-services`, and my screen looks the same as above. I even installed `dnsmasq` and `bridge-utils`. Once I do this, my other computer can connect, but it doesn't receive the proper IP address. Even when I set it manually, ping fails. Perhaps this is just broken in 14.04?

Comment: Any other solution / alternatives for ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 ?

Comment: Rohith, tried this on 14.10; not working :( what might be the issue?

Comment: Tried it on 16.04 and it does not work.

Comment: I use also Blueman - and I was able to "eliminate" the native bluetooth icon (Ubuntu 15.xx, 16.04 and now 16.10) by clicking in the main on/off at top right / System settings (or like that) / Bluetooth / Bluetooth status show up in menu (or similar).  BTW Bluetooth sharing is something "ancient", so it is very likely that phone side does not know it (meanwhile Ubuntu side provides).

Comment: works in 16.04 , see https://www.howtogeek.com/214375/how-to-reverse-tether-an-android-smartphone-or-tablet-to-your-pc/

Comment: For Ubuntu 17.10 (and probably for future versions as well), you'll need net-tools package, otherwise Apply button will fail with a "ifconfig command not found" error. You can install it by sudo apt install net-tools.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 with Android device just as described without any additional commands on Ubuntu.

**Nb:** On the **Android device** , after pairing the device with the computer:
- Click on the **Settings** (Gear icon) button near your computer from the list of paired devices;
- tick the **Internet access** option;
- and you are good to go.

Comment: Found versions of this answer all around but none of them worked for me, laptop would pair up and connect to phone, I'd tick the 'internet access' option and nothing would happen. In the end, what helped was in **blueman -> plugins** turning off **NMPAN Support** and turning on **DhcpClient**. I'd guess that'd be the equivalent of switching from "NetworkManager" to "Blueman (dhclient)" in the above window under "PAN support". Seconds after that, my phone got internet.

Comment: Need to kill dnsmasq and run it again with dhcp-option: https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/1487

Answer (score -1):

Works fine with 16.04.4

When you link your phone to your computer per bluetooth, be sure that your bluetooth works with an internet connection.
You have to wait a few seconds after the internet bluetooth link is up

Comment: OP asked how to share internet **from PC** to Phone. Kindly add more detail to your answer