# Tether mobile phone to laptop using Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, android

(I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu or an Android question - feel free to move it!)

Is it possible to connect my Android Jelly Bean phone to my laptop using bluetooth so that the telephone can use the laptop's internet connection?

```
Android --BLUETOOTH--> Laptop --ETHERNET--> Internet
```

I'm running 12.10, the laptop has bluetooth and I've been able to pair the two devices.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to create a Wifi hotspot using your Laptop and then just pick it up with the phone?.

Comment: Believe me, I agree, but Android doesn't support ad-hoc networking (not even Cyanogenmod, while iOS does) and my laptop's wifi hardware doesn't support the creation of an infrastructure hotspot.

Comment: There is a s/w in Google play that allow bluetoooth tether

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internet connection sharing from PC to Phone over Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124500/internet-connection-sharing-from-pc-to-phone-over-bluetooth)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is "reverse tethering".

I dont believe it has been done through bluetooth yet, but there's a solution that works well if you are willing to connect your phone with usb.

Find all related software and documentation here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1371345

Comment: The title of the thread you linked clearly states 'Windows Only'.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this: [Internet connection sharing from PC to Phone over Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/q/124500/263726).

I would've suggested as duplicate but I can't comment yet.