# How can I share my internet connection via bluetooth?

Tags: internet, bluetooth, connection-sharing

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 I have a hp laptop brand and I would like to share my internet connection via bluetooth

I searched on google but I found nothing serious

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Why not use ad-hoc WiFi? It's considerably simpler, and requires less finicky setup.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124500/internet-connection-sharing-from-pc-to-phone-over-bluetooth

Comment: yes thank you for your idea, but I would like to share my internet connection via bluetooth for my mobile nokia asha 300 does not feature WiFi

I managed it installed a web browser j2me able to connect to the internet via bluetooth share you understand? ;) So I managed shared my connection my phone via bluetooth will enjoy :)

Here but thank you for your advice :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd recommend you visit the post Luis Alvarado linked.

Comment: Some people prefer Bluetooth to Wifi.  I still find this useful as of 2023.

Answer (score 21):

I am not sure if there is any good way using native bluetooth app that ships with ubuntu but I am going to use a pretty old app called blueman.

install it using

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Now from untity search for blueman and you will get bluetooth manager click on that and you will get window and blueman service will be enabled.

now you can see two bluetooth icons on top panel of unity. one will be native and other will be blueman's

click on blueman's icon and click local services.

[image: selecting local services]

Now from the window click network. and enable Network Access point, click apply and save it.

[image: enabling network]

Now you can access internet using bluetooth of your computer after pairing them and connecting.

Comment: Also I am able to route android phones audio and media audio using this app :), ofcourse internet access too :)

Comment: Don't work for Nexus 5 running Android 6

Comment: Just one note: Apply button only is enabled when you modify the IP Address field (even you repeat the same IP).

Comment: @RohithRaveendran Doesn't work on Marshmallow, is there any fix

Comment: I could make it work! But, any Idea why is quite slow compared to wifi ?

Comment: @Kasun-iyambalapitiya, I have also that problem and i checked the phone bluetooth setting and seen i t have not enabled internet access on the PC paired ...

Comment: It works! but I have to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to add the standard DNS servers.