# How to share cable Internet between a PC and an iPhone?

Tags: 14.04, internet, laptop, asus, iphone

I have cable internet, and unfortunately only my PC can use it. I would like to make it so that my iPhone can also use it. I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS and an iPhone 4. Thanks!

Comment: What about an [Access Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point)?

Comment: Perhaps http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42162/ipod-reverse-tethering-via-usb might be of interest.

Comment: do you have a wifi or bluetooth adapter on your pc ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a wireless adapter you can use ap-hotspot

you can change the link if you have 64 bit

> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb

```
cd /tmp
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

usage :

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
sudo ap-hotspot restart
sudo ap-hotspot stop
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

if you dont have wifi adapter & you have bluetooth adapter

you can use this

https://askubuntu.com/a/258370/299605