# Blueman in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: internet, 16.04, bluetooth, blueman

I am trying to connect my Android phone via bluetooth to my computer's ethernet connection, but this seems not to work in Ubuntu 16.04 with blueman. I followed the steps in [Internet connection sharing from PC to Phone over Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124500/internet-connection-sharing-from-pc-to-phone-over-bluetooth), which worked flawlessly on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, but not here on this newer version.
Any suggestions?

Comment: After enabling the sharing using blueman you may have to delete the pairing and pair again with the phone so it discovers the service

Comment: @Jeremy31's Suggestion of deleting the pairing and and re-pairing resolved my issue of not being able to access Internet on my phone when connect to my laptop via Bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04.