# No "Local Services" menu item in Bluetooth Manager

Tags: ssh, bluetooth, blueman

I need to set up ssh connection to a device over bluetooth on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. There are many tutorials describing how to achieve this, but they refer to a "Local Services" menu item under the "View" menu of Bluetooth Manager (blueman).

I ave installed Blueman Device Manager version 1.23

I have no such item in the View menu, there are only items "Show Toolbar", "Show Statusbar", "Latest Device First", "Latest Device Last".

From the screenshots in the tutorials ([like this](http://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/connecting-to-the-internet-via-bluetooth/)) I see there are supposed to be two more items: "Plugins" and "Local Services". Without the "Local Services" setup, I can not make the connection to the device stable. It connects but then drops the connection after short time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the blueman icon in the notification area and select "Local Services"
[image: Picture from http://askubuntu.com/a/258370/300665]

You may also bring the dialog up with `blueman-services` in terminal

Comment: For some reason, the blueman icon is not there in the notification area. I was able to open the dialog by running the blueman-services and successfully complete the ssh connection.