# Problems sharing internet to my phone

Tags: bluetooth, dhcp, phone

I was looking in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124500/internet-connection-sharing-from-pc-to-phone-over-bluetooth) to give my phone internet from my computer. But then I got this:
[image: No DHCP servers installed]

I am really new in ubuntu and I don't know how to fix that.
What do I have to do to install a DHCP server and get internet for my phone?

Comment: Please take into account that Bluetooth tethering is someting "ancient". It can happen easily that your phone does not support it. I suggest you wifi AP instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `dnsmasq` (DHCP server) is not installed in your system.

To install `dnsmasq` type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

To configure `dnsmasq`visit this link: [Dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq)